# NSMutableDictonary of NSString getting null value

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm creating a NSMutableDictonary:

```
dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

And after adding string items:

```
[dict setObject:@"three" forKey:@"apple"];
[dict setObject:@"factory" forKey:@"car"];
[dict setObject:@"big bang" forKey:@"earth"];
```

I got the values if I try to access right after this. But if I try to access sometime after I got null value.

I belive it's because these strings is autoreleased. Then, the question is: What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: We need to see more code since what you’ve pasted is correct. Is `dict` an instance variable? Do you send it `-removeObjectForKey:` somewhere? Also, literal strings are not autoreleased and, even if they were, Cocoa collections own the objects added to them and the keys are always copied.

Comment: I agree with Bavarious. One vote up for him.

Answer (score 0):

Really sorry guys! The example that I put here works, fine! The problem was the newbie debugging the code, me, making mistake about where is the problem. I was putting null value, believing that wasn't.

Thanks all.